# Issue with Linksys router connection

Tags: wireless-router

I bought a linksys router one week ago.  It worked well but then it fell and I cannot get any connection.  I tried resetting but it showed connection until i tried connecting to the net it failed.  The signal strength is excellent but it kept showing a yellow exclamation sign.  i tried troubleshooting but it kept saying the modem is not connected.

Comment: Please clarify: What Linksys (Model number)? Since you mentioned Signal Strength, this is a Wireless capable router? And yellow exclamation sign - connecting from a Windows machine? Do you get any IP address? Does the linksys router have DHCP enabled?

Comment: It worked, it fell, now it does not work. Seems likely that you broke it by allowing it to fall. Returning it as suggested would be IMHO a bit dishonest. Unless you have some sort of insurance (ie, sometimes credit cards add damage/loss if you bought it with Card X) just buy another one and don't let it fall.

Comment: You reset the router? mmm, is that to default factory or just a powercycle? Cause if it is factory reset, then you'll have to configure your router to authenticate with the ISP again and then you will have internet. Sounds like you do have network access, just not internet.

Answer (score 0):

If you bought it a week ago, you might try returning it to the store you bought it from and exchanging it for another one, a different model,  or a different brand altogether.